# how to use insert query when we create database and table in onclick method

Tags: android, sqlite

i create database and table in onclick method of button(save). when click on save button then database and table is created. i can take 5 edittext for output. In this program, user can't input the value. for example timer control. in timer application, when user press start button then countdown timer is started, he press stop button then values are stopped and that values are stored in the database when he press save button. so i can create database and table on save button. please give me suggestion and code for inserting the outout value not like user inputted value in database.
My code is following:

Code:

---

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent =new Intent(Timedetails.this,ListActivity.class); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Project has been added to List", 1).show();
        startActivity(intent);
            try{

                        SQLiteDatabase db;
                db = openOrCreateDatabase("timer", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                db.execSQL("create table timerdetail("
                        + "project_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
                        + "name text,"
                        + "Timerpoint1 text,"
                        + "Timerpoint2 text,"
                        + "Timerpoint3 text,"
                        + "ServiceTime1 text,"
                        + "ServiceTime2 text);");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table is created", 1).show();


            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Y u are creating multiple database and table on save click time? You can just create database and table at once when the application start and it will be take care it self. For save you just get the data of timer and insert into the table on save click time

Comment: r u  know database properly?? In source code only one database and only one table is there. please check again.

Comment: Yes I have seen the code that's why I asking you. Each time when you click on button it will call the create/open database it's ok but you execute create table query each time I didn't understand this

Comment: db = openOrCreateDatabase("timer", MODE_PRIVATE, null); This statement help us to only one time create database and table. This statement check if database already exist then it doesn't create table or database. My problem is not regarding on creating database or table but "how to insert values in that table???"

Comment: no one can have answer this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for insertion:

```
ContentValues cvTimerDtl = new ContentValues();
cvTimerDtl.put("name", name);
cvTimerDtl.put("Timerpoint1", tPoint1);
cvTimerDtl.put("Timerpoint2", tPoint2);
cvTimerDtl.put("Timerpoint3", tPoint3);
cvTimerDtl.put("ServiceTime1", sTime1);
cvTimerDtl.put("ServiceTime2", sTime2);
db.insert("timerdetail",  null, cvTimerDtl);
```

Edit:
I think it should work. But still I am posting another code:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO timerdetail (name, Timerpoint1, Timerpoint2, Timerpoint3, ServiceTime1, ServiceTime2) VALUES ('"
                + name + "', '" + tPoint1 + "', '" + tPoint2 + "', '" + tPoint3 + "', '" + sTime1 + "', '" + sTime2 + "');";

db.execSQL(query);
```

Edit:

Your onClick code starts intent first and then you try to insert data into database:
Change it as follows:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try{
                    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("data/data/com.example.timerdemo2/timer", null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

                    //db = openOrCreateDatabase("timer", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    db.execSQL("create table timerdetail("
                            + "project_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
                            + "name text,"
                            + "Timerpoint1 text,"
                            + "Timerpoint2 text,"
                            + "Timerpoint3 text,"
                            + "ServiceTime1 text,"
                            + "ServiceTime2 text);");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table is created", 1).show();

            //      db.execSQL("insert into timerdetail(name,tmpoint1,tmpoint2,tmpoint3,servicetime1,servicetime2) values ();");
    /*              ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    //cv.put("name", eta.getText().toString());
                    cv.put("timing_point1", eta.getText().toString());
                    cv.put("timing_point2", etb.getText().toString());
                    cv.put("timing_point3", etc.getText().toString());
                    int rowposition = (int) db.insert("timerdetail", null, cv);     */
                    addRecord();

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            Intent intent =new Intent(Timedetails.this,ListActivity.class); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Project has been added to List", 1).show();
            startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Edit:

Change

```
db.execSQL("create table timerdetail("
                            + "project_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
                            + "name text,"
                            + "Timerpoint1 text,"
                            + "Timerpoint2 text,"
                            + "Timerpoint3 text,"
                            + "ServiceTime1 text,"
                            + "ServiceTime2 text);");
```

to

```
db.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS timerdetail("
                            + "project_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
                            + "name text,"
                            + "Timerpoint1 text,"
                            + "Timerpoint2 text,"
                            + "Timerpoint3 text,"
                            + "ServiceTime1 text,"
                            + "ServiceTime2 text);");
```

So the table won't be created if it already exists.

Edit:

If you want to put x number of columns, your content values will contain that many key value pairs. So if you want to add title in database, too. Change content values as

```
ContentValues cvTimerDtl = new ContentValues();

cvTimerDtl.put("title", title);
cvTimerDtl.put("name", name);
cvTimerDtl.put("Timerpoint1", tPoint1);
cvTimerDtl.put("Timerpoint2", tPoint2);
cvTimerDtl.put("Timerpoint3", tPoint3);
cvTimerDtl.put("ServiceTime1", sTime1);
cvTimerDtl.put("ServiceTime2", sTime2);
db.insert("timerdetail",  null, cvTimerDtl);
```

Comment: @user204406 Yes. After creating table. Because you want to create table and insert data on button's click only. So

Comment: i already try this code but this code is not effected. so you have any more code for insert value at button's click event then send me..

Comment: ok i can try.thanx. you r very help me. i check code and reply to you.

Comment: @user204406, These queries work perfectly for me. So there must be some other issue. Please post your updated code

Comment: actually, i post the code but it is not posted, if you are understand then i write the step for database and insert query in comment.

Comment: first of all, on button click event, i create database ...my code try{
     
       SQLiteDatabase db;                                                db = openOrCreateDatabase("timer", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("create table timerdetail("
 + "project_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
 + "name text,"
 + "Timerpoint1 text,"
 + "Timerpoint2 text,"
 + "Timerpoint3 text,"
 + "ServiceTime1 text,"
 + "ServiceTime2 text);");
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table is created",1).show();

Comment: after creating table, i write insert query...........................db.execSQL("insert into timerdetail(name,tmpoint1,tmpoint2,tmpoint3,servicetime1,servicetime2) values ();");
 /*    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
     //cv.put("name", eta.getText().toString());
     cv.put("timing_point1", eta.getText().toString());
     cv.put("timing_point2", etb.getText().toString());
     cv.put("timing_point3", etc.getText().toString());
     int rowposition = (int) db.insert("timerdetail", null, cv);     */
     addRecord();

Comment: i use addRecord method for edittext's id fetch.private void addRecord() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String tmp1 = eta.getText().toString();
    String tmp2 = etb.getText().toString();
    String tmp3 = etc.getText().toString();
    String ser1 = service1.getText().toString();
    String ser2 = service2.getText().toString();
    insertData(tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,ser1,ser2);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record inserted suceessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
   }

Comment: so, if you have any idea Shreya then please tell me... thanx lot.

Comment: Shreya shah, u are so amazing. My insert code is sucessfully work. Thank you very very very very very much....

Comment: @user204406, so what was the problem?

Comment: problem is in insert statement, i use these insert statement "db.insert("timerdetail", null, cv);". Using this code record successfully inserted but next problem is that "record is insrted only one time, when i run program second time but second value is not inserted". if you have any suggestion for this please give me hint.

Comment: @user204406, Please try to post your onClickListener's code in your question

Comment: shreya, i post my code but it takes lots of time for process. so i think my stackoverflow account is not response more. so please give me suggestion how to post my code??

Comment: @jack, yes. Checking it. Whn u try to insert it 2nd time? Does it throw any exception?

Comment: no, no exception is thrown but when i insert second value in logcat then following error display. "table timerdetail already exists". i think when i insert second value then table is created second time. so i use the "db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
"sdcard/myfriendsDB",
null,
SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);" but not effected. If you have any idea then share with me.

Comment: @jack. Check the edit: Table creation query will be changed a bit and your problem will be solved.

Comment: thank you very much shreya, You are outstanding... Record Inserted Sucessfully second time. Tankx lot lot lot... I heartly thanx.

Comment: my next question is "how to show inserted record on listview in second activity??"

Comment: @jack, Check this tutorial and implement accordingly for that: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2011/02/listview-of-data-from-sqlitedatabase.html

Comment: @jack, what exactly do u mean? U are already inserting your query.

Comment: i used edittext value for insert statement but i have one title, which is textview and i want to insert it to database. if you have any idea then share with me. if you want to show code then i send at http://pastie.org/.

Comment: @jack You can use txtview.getText() for getting textview's text

Comment: i already use this code but code is not work, i make one string like tv and then pass tv to TextView tv1 object like (tv = tv1.getText.toString); but the null values are display. If you want to see code then i send it on http://pastie.org/.

Comment: @jack, yes, please post the link

Comment: @jack String tv = tv1.getText().toString(); will come after tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Projecttitle);

Comment: no, i tried but not work, i send whole activity code on http://pastie.org/. please check.

Comment: @jack, I already checked your code. You have wrote  String tv = tv1.getText().toString(); line before declaring your textview as tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Projecttitle);  So you are getting null value. Just interchange those lines

Comment: i interchange the line but force to close error is display. but i will try to another way for getting textview value in insert statement.

Comment: @jack, What is your current code? http://pastie.org/5587366 or http://pastie.org/5587334 ?

Comment: @jack, You are already calling tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Projecttitle); in onCreate(). So you don't need to call it again in addRecord() method. And if you are setting title dynamically using String title, then why are you not using query as insertData(title,tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,ser1,ser2); ? You don't need to retrieve textview data at all

Comment: As u suggest, when i take title for insert statement insertData(title,tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,ser1,ser2); then name column of table is null. name is not display in inserted record.

Comment: how to fetch database when it is created in button's click event(onClickListener) to another activity like showdataActivity??

Comment: how to fetch database when it is created in button's click event(onClickListener) to another activity like showdataActivity for show inserted record in listview??

Comment: shreya, i need your help for displaying data on next activity. i done insert, now i want to display data on next activity in Listview. PLease help me.